# Problem with removing rpm package

Tags: centos, rpm

I'm trying to install one package on CentOS 6.7

`yum install varnish`

but I'm getting that I have a package which doesn't belongs there (is for CentOS 7)

`---> Package varnish.x86_64 0:4.1.0-1.el7 will be installed`

which creates problems during installation. Trying to update to correct one package

`rpm --nosignature -U --oldpackage  https://repo.varnish-cache.org/redhat/varnish-4.1.el6.rpm`

returns `package varnish-release-4.1-2.el6.noarch is already installed`

Running `rpm -qa | grep varnish` gives `varnish-release-4.1-2.el6.noarch` so how can I remove package for CentOS 7 when is not listed there so I can install correct varnish version?

`yum --showduplicates search varnish`

returns

`varnish-docs-2.1.5-5.el6.x86_64 : Documentation files for varnish
varnish-libs-2.1.5-5.el6.i686 : Libraries for varnish
varnish-libs-2.1.5-5.el6.x86_64 : Libraries for varnish
varnish-libs-devel-2.1.5-5.el6.i686 : Development files for varnish-libs
varnish-libs-devel-2.1.5-5.el6.x86_64 : Development files for varnish-libs
varnish-2.1.5-5.el6.x86_64 : High-performance HTTP accelerator`

still nothing related to `varnish.x86_64 0:4.1.0-1.el7`

Comment: What's the output of `yum --showduplicates search varnish`?

Comment: @Dani_l OP updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, i have founded `varnish 4.1.0-1.el7` in `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/epel/`. Strange. Have removed that folder and reloaded correct package - all went back to normal state.

Comment: Awesome, I would have never guesses that yum would have a cache!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rpm -qa | grep varnish | xargs rpm -e
```

to remove every varnish package installed.

Comment: `rpm: no packages given for erase`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the rpms in the [repository](https://repo.varnish-cache.org/redhat/varnish-4.1/el7/noarch/varnish-release/)
it seems that rpm `varnish-release-4.1-2.el6.noarch.rpm` just contains
an entry for yum to use. Try removing

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/varnish-4.1.repo
```

and any other versions in that directory and start again.

Comment: There is no repo with that name. It looks like `varnish.x86_64 0:4.1.0-1.el7` came from a RPM